# Magento 2 - How to get custom dropdown value from checkout with knockout js

Tags: knockout.js, magento2

I had developed extension which is create one custom dropdown field in checkout.I want to display selected dropdown value in order summary dynamically when i have select option from select(dropdown) field.

Here is my screen shot of select(dropdown) field of dealer.

[image]

When i have select dealer dropdown option value, at that time display dealer select field value in order summary. Here is display field in order summary.

[image]

For this i have create one dealer.js file in web folder.

```
define(['jquery', 'uiComponent', 'ko'], function ($, Component, ko) {
        'use strict';
        return Component.extend({
            value : ko.observable(),
            initialize: function () {
                this._super();
            }

        });

    }
);
```

And also create html template dealer.html file in web folder.

```
<div class="dealerblock">
    <span class="labletxt">Dealer</span>
    <div data-bind="text: value"></div>
</div>
```

Both js and html file are called in checkout using checkout_index_index.xml but not reflecting value when i have change option of dealer dropdown field.

Please help me for display selected value of dealer dropdown field in order summary.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please provide fiddle for that ?

Comment: sorry, I have no fiddle for this

Comment: can you please explain me over here ? please

Comment: i have one example of fiddle :  http://jsfiddle.net/b30tvt44/193/

Comment: I want to implement same functionality in magento 2.